# find a particular page in orchard migration

Tags: orchardcms

So I am adding a page via the migration.cs file and this is working fine.
The issue comes that if I run the Update twice it will add the page twice.
While I know that in stage/prod this will not be the case. 
But in dev we rerun the release code a few times to get it all working.

anyway what I want is something like

```
        private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;

// this line is made up
var articleListingPage = _contentManager.GetPages.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "ArticleListingPage");
if (articleListingPage  == null)
{
  var articlesPage = _contentManager.Create("Page");
            articlesPage.As<TitlePart>().Title = "ArticleList";
            articlesPage.As<BodyPart>().Text = @"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mauris magna, varius vel vulputate eget, bibendum id magna.</p>";
            articlesPage.As<CommonPart>().Owner = _orchardServices.WorkContext == null ? null : _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser;

            var articlesRoute = articlesPage.As<AutoroutePart>();
            articlesRoute.DisplayAlias = _autorouteService.GenerateAlias(articlesRoute);
            _autorouteService.PublishAlias(articlesRoute);

            var menu = _menuService.GetMenu("Main Menu");
            if (menu == null) throw new Exception("Could not get the menu. Please the name of the menu is correct.");
            articlesPage.As<MenuPart>().Menu = menu;
            articlesPage.As<MenuPart>().MenuText = "Article List YYYY";
            articlesPage.As<MenuPart>().MenuPosition = "10";

            _contentManager.Publish(articlesPage);
}
```

Does anyone know how to find a collections of pages/content?

Comment: Please keep in mind that migrations are not designed to create contents, but to mutate the data schema. The right way to bring new contents in is recipes.

Comment: Can you apply a new recipe at Update2 say?

Comment: I think you could, yes, but I'd say it's better in general if schema mutation and data creation stay separated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As its dynamics its based on the Content Parts in the item.
In this example the "TitlePart" is added to the content type "Page"

```
 var list = _contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Published, "Page")
                .List().Cast<dynamic>();
 var existingPage = list.Any(i => i.TitlePart.Title == "ArticleList");

 if (existingPage == false)
{
      //add page etc

}
```